# How to display speak stuff no selection by true or false if speak stuff property is null or no values?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I work on asp.net MVC web app I face issue i can't make check box no

selection if value of `speakstuff` property is null so i will not make

default value false .

i need `speakstuff` property when display for first

time of user to display as null so how to change my code to accept if

`speakstuff` is null then no checked checkbox selection by true or false

my code as below :

my code what i try as below

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('.speak-stuff-checkbox').on('change', function () {
            $('.speak-stuff-checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', false);
            var selectedValue = $(this).val();
            $('#SpeakStuff').val(selectedValue);
        });
      
        });

     @Html.Label("Did You Meet/Speak to Staff", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-5" })
     <div class="col-md-7">
        

         <input type="checkbox" id="SpeakStuff" name="SpeakStuff" value="true" class="speak-stuff-checkbox" @(Model.SpeakStuff ? "checked" : "") disabled />
         Yes
         &nbsp;&nbsp;
         <input type="checkbox" id="SpeakStuff" name="SpeakStuff" value="false" class="speak-stuff-checkbox" @(!Model.SpeakStuff ? "checked" : "") disabled />
         No



     </div>

 public class ResignationRequester
 {
     
public int RequestNo { get; set; }
public bool SpeakStuff { get; set; }
 }
```

when assign value to `speakstuff` property it made as below :

```
obj.SpeakStuff = F6000059["REEV01"].ToString().ToUpper() == "Y" ? true : false;
```

Comment: Please rewrite the question to make sense. You break the sentences in a weird way, have no punctuation and repeat yourself.  Perhaps use a better translator?

Comment: Also why not speakStaff when it is "Did you talk to `staff`"

Answer (score 1):

Trying to answer this as if you asked

*How can I modify my C# and JavaScript code for an ASP.NET MVC web app to ensure that the checkbox for the "SpeakStuff" property remains unchecked (neither true nor false) when it is initially null, and only becomes checked if a value is assigned to it?*

1. Use the null conditional operator (`?.`)

   ```
   obj.SpeakStuff = F6000059["REEV01"]?.ToString().ToUpper() == "Y";
   ```
2. Change the checkboxes

   ```
   <label><input type="checkbox" id="SpeakStuffTrue" name="SpeakStuff" value="true" class="speak-stuff-checkbox" 
     @(Model.SpeakStuff ? "checked" : "") disabled />Yes</label>
   <label><input type="checkbox" id="SpeakStuffFalse" name="SpeakStuff" value="false" class="speak-stuff-checkbox" 
     @(!Model.SpeakStuff ? "checked" : "") disabled />No</label>
   ```
3. I see code where you try to code checkboxes as radios. Why not use radios?